# using jQuery delegate in a JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

If I am writing a jQuery plugin as

```
$.fn.newWin = function(docTypes) { 
                    $(this).live("click",function(){
                                    alert("I am done");
                    }); 
              };
```

This plugin can be invoked as

```
$("#content a, #partners a").newWin();
```

Basically what I want is to swap `.live` with `.delegate`. How can I achieve that as I have to pass the callee element string to the `.delegate` function also?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend you to use delegate here. If you can (as of jQuery 1.7), use `.on()` instead

```
$.fn.newWin = function(docTypes) { 
      $(this).on("click",function(){
            alert("I am done");
      }); 
};
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend `delegate` instead of `live`? Please explain.

Comment: @Tadeck: I didn't say I would recommend to use delegate over live. But I wouldn't recommend to use delegate over on

Comment: On the other hand, if you intend to publish your plugin, it's a good idea to use `delegate` for backwards compatibility. `delegate` gets converted to `on` internally by jQuery 1.7 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve (the actual architecture of your plugin). But it may look as follows:

```
$.fn.newWin = function(elements_selector) {
    $(this).delegate(elements_selector, "click",function(){
        alert("I am done");
    });
};
```

and can be invoked like that:

```
$("#content, #partners").newWin("a");
```

In case of jQuery newer than 1.7 you should however switch to `.on()` instead of `.live()` or `.delegate()`. See [documentation of `.on()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Is that what you expected?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at jQuery 1.7 yet.  Does it look like they're planning to replace `delegate`, `live`, `click`, etc with `.on()`?  I saw a comment in the repo today that they're itching for a code reduction release.

Comment: @JimSchubert: Since 1.7 and since `.on()` is available, they are suggesting usage of `.on()` instead of `.live()`, `.delegate()` and `.bind()`. But they are not mentioning `.click()`, `.hover()` and other shortcuts - probably if they are still a shortcut to `.bind()`, then they are probably deprecated since 1.7, but if they are changed to depend on `.on()`, they will probably not stay deprecated. Hope this is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.newPlug = function(){
    var selector = $(this).selector;
    $(document.body).delegate(selector, 'click', function(){
        // do something...
    });
};
```

look at this!